# Objective-C NSScrollView Foreground Colour

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsscrollview, nscolor

I am getting into app development and just started using NSScrollViews to display large chunks of text.

I am able to set the background colour by writing the following:

```
[_HeadersScrollView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor darkGrayColor]];
```

But not set the foreground colour by doing something similar to:

```
[_HeadersScrollView setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]]; // nope
[_HeadersScrollView setForegroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]]; // nope
[_HeadersScrollView setForeground:[NSColor whiteColor]]; // nope
```

Is there a method or any other way that I could get this type of setup to work? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: A scroll view doesn't have a foreground color because it's not in the foreground. It's a container. If it drew in front of the contained views, you wouldn't be able to see them. What do you expect the foreground color to affect? Perhaps you're using a text view (`NSTextView`) that's inside a scroll view and you want to affect that. You can call `-setTextColor:` on an `NSTextView` (it inherits it from `NSText`).

Comment: I'm not actually sure. I typed in "NSTextView" and I dragged it into my NSViewController, and it magically turned into NSScrollView. I just went with it.

Comment: The `NSScrollView` contains an `NSClipView` (a helper for scrolling) which contains the `NSTextView`. If you want to operate on the text view you either need an outlet to that or you can request the `documentView` from the scroll view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSScrollView` contains an `NSClipView` (a helper for scrolling) which contains the `NSTextView`. If you want to operate on the text view you either need an outlet to that or you can request the `documentView` from the scroll view.

You can do either:

```
[_HeadersScrollView.documentView setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
```

Or, if you have an outlet to the text view (called `_textView` in my example), you can do:

```
 _textView.textColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
```

In this case, you would probably want to set the background color on the text view, too, rather than the scroll view. And tell it to draw its background by setting `drawsBackground`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for explaining the `NSScrollView` to me! :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no setting like that for changing foreground color in scrollview.

_HeadersScrollView.tintColor = [NSColor whiteColor];

or

[_HeadersScrollView setTintColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];

Comment: Might there be a reason why there's no NSTextView thing in xcode when making mac apps? Why only an nsscrollview?

Comment: Oh, and your code doesn't work. Method doesn't exist.